# Mix pet pal with know-it-all

Tags: divinity-original-sin

Does it make sense to give those two to one character? Do I need points in charisma to use pet pal effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, they're not related at all. **Pet Pal** is not affected by anything else (like charisma), it just enables you to talk to animals. The lower attitude from **Know-it-all** is not offset by **Charisma**, but a different mechanism entirely (one negative effect is prices when trading, which can be offset by **Bartering**). Most humanoids can also be bribed for increased attitude, although this is rarely necessary.

All other mechanisms work as normal and there aren't that many charisma checks in conversations with animals, they're usually quite happy to be able to converse with you at all instead of getting an arrow in the hock.